# Unable to execute cucumber test through Maven project

Tags: selenium, maven, junit, cucumber, testng

**The details for pom file, runner file and console output are given below**

Pom.xml file- Describes the dependencies and plugins used

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
         <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
         <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
         <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
         <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
         <version>6.9.1</version>
         <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>26.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  
  <build>
  <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
       <filtering>true</filtering>
     </resource>
   </resources>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration> 
                <testSourceDirectory>Adminportal/src/test/java/com/vnext/Testrunner</testSourceDirectory>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/CucumberRunnerTest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```

**Cucumber Runner file**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"/src/test/resource/Features"}
        ,glue={"com.vnext.stepDefinition"}, tags=  "@Login", dryRun=true, monochrome=true
        , plugin = {"pretty", "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html" }
        )

public class CucumberRunnerTest {
    
    public static Properties testProp;
    public static String driverPath;
    public static String browser;
    public static String environment;
    public static LinkedHashMap<String, String> envProperty = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    public static JsonReader jr;
    private static DriverLaunch  dl= new DriverLaunch();
    String envRootDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void suitSetup() throws Exception{
        testProp = PropertyFileUtils.readProperty(envRootDir+"/src/test/resource/Properties/Test.properties");
        driverPath= testProp.getProperty("driverPath");
        browser= testProp.getProperty("browser");
        environment = testProp.getProperty("environment");
        System.out.println("Driver Path : "+driverPath);
        System.out.println("Browser : "+browser);
        jr= new JsonReader();
        envProperty=JsonReader.jsonRead(environment, envRootDir+"/src/test/resource/DBSite/DbSiteData.json");
        dl.launchDriver(browser, driverPath);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void teardown(){
        dl.tearDown();
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("config/report.xml"));
    }
    
    @AfterSuite
    public void endConnection(){
    }
```

**Console output**

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.vnext.Testrunner.CucumberRunnerTest
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.561 s - in com.vnext.Testrunner.CucumberRunnerTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.954 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-14T00:44:13+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/497M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**The code is not getting executed. Maven is ignoring the feature file . Please help me resolve the issue. I tried commenting the Runwith tag but then also getting the same result.**

Please Help!

Comment: You have way to many things going on in your question. This means it is hard for people to help if, if they can do it at all. Start from scratch with a demo project. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a few incompatible and unnecessary dependencies in your pom. I suggest you start with the starter project: github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/

Answer (score 0):

create a separate junit runner class :

```
package options;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = "pretty",
        glue = "stepdefs",   // the package containing step definitions
        features = "src/test/features")   //the folder where you have your featurefile
public class CucumberTests {
}
```

Now just run :

```
mvn test
```

Comment: made changes and ran but no success